# Can I post-process this out of focus image?

Tags: post-processing, focus

There was a small snake hiding in the grass. I pointed my camera, but I zoomed too much. When I pressed the button to adjust the focus, the autofocus complained because it was out of range. I tried again, but I pressed too much and I shot a picture out of focus. Then I changed the zooming level, but in that fraction of a second, the snake and  the good frame were gone. I tried to sharpen the image with Gimp unsharp mask, but it is too much out of focus. Is there another way to sharpen the image?

[image]

Comment: I think you're going to have to put that one down to experience & wait for next time. Sorry.

Comment: For comparison… I once spent a week on holiday trying to catch a picture of a bee [or if not **one** bee, a close relative]  on a specific flower it would visit half a dozen times a day & give me the "perfect" opportunity. I think I got one usable shot out of perhaps 300 fails.

Comment: If only you had had a [light field camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-field_camera) ...

Comment: If you have a lot of other images of snakes in grass, you could train a neural network to perform super resolution. This technique is shown there : http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2020spr/report/Garber_Grossman_Johnson-Yu.pdf

Comment: Snakes are hard because they move quickly (sometimes) and are hidden in vegetation (sometimes).  The ones that are out sunning and still are easy.  The ones you see before they see you are relatively easy, especially if you have a long lens and manual focus.  Auto focus often gets confused by the vegetation.  If you see it because it moves your odds are very low.  This is much better than I get most of the time if the snake is already moving.  A DSLR with phase autofocus and set with aperture priority, f/16 and ISO 1600 is probably your best bet.

Comment: BTW, I did throw that image through "everything I could think of", manual, auto & AI-based before my first comment. With some, I could get the grass at the back sharp enough to cut yourself on, but the snake & in front are beyond recovery.

Comment: Mastering focus is a hard skill - it takes time, lots of practice, and lots of quality time with your camera getting to know its capabilities, quirks, and behaviour.  Every camera is a bit different, every lens is a bit different, and all have an array of tools to help you get the focus you want quickly... but it takes time to learn.  Nothing will fix an out of focus image, unfortunately.  Just keep practising.

Comment: Do you have a link to a higher quality (lossless possibly ?) of your image ?

Answer (score 32):

Yes of course it can be post processed. It might make it “better.”

But it will never make it the picture you wish it was.

The good news is that there will be other snakes on other days. Plenty of chances to make better snake pictures lie in the future if you want.

There are good reasons to work on pictures that probably can’t be saved. One is to practice using post processing tools. You will understand what is possible. And what is not. And develop intuition for what might be.

In the long run, most of the pictures we make turn out worse than we wanted. Experience teaches us that the way to get the good ones is to focus on trying to make them and not worry about the ones that got away.

The only way not to make pictures that are not good enough is to not make pictures.

Comment: Since this appears to be a case of almost-purely defocus, it's more or less trivial to find a kernel function which remaps intensities back to the focus point for each object point.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That might make it better. It won’t make it the picture the photographer wishes they had made. I know there are people who find fixing pictures more interesting than making pictures that don’t need fixing. They tend to get better at fixing pictures more quickly than at making them. Anyway I don’t believe there is a silver bullet, and it is better to commit to the hard work now rather than pretend Charlie Brown is going to kick the football. YMMV.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The OP only asked to get rid of blur, and a good spherical defocus kernel will  clean up the image beyond what our eyes can perceive.

Answer (score 4):

Better than sharpen, you can deblur the image. You could use techniques that are not usual in consumer photography such as [*blind deconvolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution), or patch-based techniques such as [*BM3D deblur*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=bm3d%20deblurr) which can deblur from one single image. There are other techniques.

You can use Matlab (a standard tool in computer vision) to apply those techniques (implementations of those exist), and Photoshop can use Matlab functions, which is practical for applications on images.

Example with **blind deconvolution**:

[image: blind deconvolution]

Example with **BM3D**:

[image: BM3D deblur]

Comment: Do you think the algorithms mentioned will do as well with a full color image?

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Of course they will - you can deblur R,G,B separately, then deblur a grayscale version, and do some weighted fusion of the results.

Comment: **This answer could be much more convincing if you took the OP's photo, applied the technique, and showed the results.** If what you propose is truly feasible, then certainly it shouldn't be too much trouble to demonstrate it. In my experience, more often than not, techniques developed for scientific image processing do not work for photography, and do no produce an image which is aesthetically acceptable (even if some details could be enhanced). E.g. your examples don't have depth of field.

Comment: -1 for the very strong statement "My opinion is that your image can definitely be salvaged.", provided without evidence or instructions on how to make it happen. The examples you show have been convolved with a constant kernel. The second one has clearly been convolved computationally (it's not an out-of-focus image).

Comment: Importantly, the pyramids image is pretty much all at "infinity", optically speaking, whereas the photograph in the question has a much deeper field (i.e. much of it is closer than the subject of interest).

Comment: @TobySpeight The field is bigger at infinity don't you think ? It's actually more varied in the OP and heterogenous (due to the shape of the "object"), hence a certain difficulty to process satisfyingly with one "operation".

Comment: @Soleil, I think you've expressed what I meant much better than I managed to.  Thank you!

Comment: @Szabolcs What is "scientific image processing" ? Does is start with demosaicking, denoising, or what ? Everybody with a digital camera does directly or not such "scientific image processing" don't you thing ? I did not try everything recent, but I used patch-based techniques many times (including BM3D denoising) more satisfyingly than consumer's basic operations. Many "advanced" techniques are used every day in astrophotography, microscopy, and in smartphones, and give excellent results. Anyway, the OP was asking about techniques other than "sharpening", and I provided few of them.

Comment: @Szabolcs I removed the opinion-based part of my answer, which is, I agree, better without. You stated "your examples don't have depth of field" which is wrong, it can be homogenous or big, and still exist, rather, the subject is affected homogenously by the depth of field.

Comment: Can you show an actual example of one of these methods applied to the OP's image?